# Template specialization, specialized class question

Tags: c++

I have the following code and when I compile in section A, the function doesn't match the template specialization.  Does anyone know what this is occurring?

I have defined a specialized class in the #ifdef code.

Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T1, class T2, int I>
class A {
public:
    void f0();
};            

template<class T1, class T2, int I>
void A<T1, T2, I>::f0()
{
    cout << "x" << endl;
}

#if 0 // A
template<>
class A<int, int, 4> {
public:
    void f0();
};
#endif

template<>
void A<int, int, 4>::f0()
{
    cout << "z" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    A<int, int, 4> a0;
    a0.f0();
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation error when #ifdef is compiled in:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall test177.cc && ./a.out
test177.cc:25:22: error: no function template matches function template
      specialization 'f0'
void A<int, int, 4>::f0()
```

Comment: I am confused. The code isn't working when class specialization is defined? Or the opposite?

Comment: The code doesn't work when the #if def'd section is compiled.  As is, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write the member function without "template<>" like bellow:

```
template<>
class A<int, int, 4> {
public:
    void f0();
};

void A<int, int, 4>::f0()
{
    cout << "z" << endl;
}
```

please refer to document of the compile error:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/blob/master/docs/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2910.md

Comment: do you know why the second template <> causes the problem?  I don't see that in this document

Comment: @notaorb I am not sure actually... I guess that speciallization of class A with "template<>"  is done at declaration of specialized A.

Comment: @notaorb It's because `A<int, int, 4>::foo()` is not a `template`, it's a function on a fully specialized class template. The definition of the _class_ `A<int, int, 4>` requires `template<>` because this is where you specialize the template `A` -- but all other references to this type, or things relating to this type, are effectively "concrete" types, just as any other class

Comment: @Human-Compiler thanks, but I don't think this is the case for the code that compiles which is posted.  `template<> void A<int, int, 4>::f0()` is a function on a fully specialized class template, but removing the `template <>` causes  compilation error.